Какой знак препинания, на ваш взгляд, наиболее уместен на месте двоеточия?
Если вы заблудились в лесу, посмотрите на мох: зелёный цвет успокаивает.

А Вам двоеточие здесь почему не понравилось?

Мне двоеточие очень нравится, но хочется понять, возможны ли более удачные варианты

Если вы заблудились в лесу, посмотрите на мох — зелёный цвет успокаивает.
Пояснение
Выбор в БСП невелик: двоеточие, тире, запятая. Запятая не подойдет, а выбор между тире и двоеточием делается по контексту. Если тема зеленого цвета будет продолжена, то лучше поставить тире, если тема на этом закончится закончится, то двоеточие.
1. Розенталь § 72. Вариативные знаки препинания. Двоеточие — тире
4. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных 
предложениях с причинно-следственными отношениями. Ср.:
Последние дни флажки на карте не двигались: положение 
оставалось без перемен (Сим.); А углубляться мы не могли — 
земля промёрзла (Гран.).
Ср. также: Кажется, Приморью и без того есть чем подивить 
мир (: —) одни тигры да женьшень чего стоят; Эти слова при 
нём не произносите (: —) может обидеться; С таким напарником 
можно хоть на Марс лететь (: —) надёжный товарищ.


Двоеточие по смыслу и интонации часто заменяется тире, обозначая различные отношения, в том числе причинно- следственные. Для двоеточия характерно интонационное предупреждение о последующем раскрытии темы (подчеркнутая пауза, неполное понижение тона), а при постановке тире голос тоже понижается, на пауза меньше.

